# Magento 2.4.2 invalid date format by default, can't change date format in UI component

Tags: magento2, cms, cms-pages, date, format

I would like to specify the date format for a new date field in my CMS page form. I have created a new cms_page_form.xml field which links to a date field in the MySQL database table cms_page. However, MySQL rejects the field because it is in the wrong format. I have tried setting the format in many different ways: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TjJ6.png (also without the item options array), literally spending hours trying to set it in cms_page_form.xml with the official documentation for the Date component not providing much of any help: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-date.html

I have even tried creating my own UI component (also specifying the new component /form/element/date etc of course) with just time as an example, and just time does work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXRBI.png however when I change it to use date and specify the custom date format in JavaScript, it still doesn't work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx2r9.png it just uses today's date in the wrong format: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcOCe.png

Here is my cms_page_form.xml with the date formatting not working: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TjJ6.png

When I load the CMS page, by default, it displays "Invalid date": https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYxj9.png then quickly changes over to today's date - in the wrong format: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5zj4.png

**All I want is a date input with the format of yyyy-MM-dd in my CMS page form in Magento 2.4.2**

If anyone could help me with this I would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add date Format

```
<column name="run_time" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Run Time</item>
            <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string" translate="true">MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss a</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Now delete the records that you find from a ui_bookmark table.

Clear the cache

See more: https://www.screencast.com/t/qePBLRpe27

Comment: At first I tried copying just the date format but it didn't change the date format it was still the same, then I tried copying the argument block and it didn't work it threw an error about uid is not defined, then I tried copying the class type as well and it still threw a slightly different error about uid is not defined: https://i.imgur.com/lZAYWR9.png

When copying the entire column block, it says that column is not allowed here (in my cms_page_form.xml): https://i.imgur.com/rb6ndXa.png